# PHP PDO, SQL update conflicting with the function "lastInsertd()"

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have this code below, but it has a problem: if i call the function 'updateData()' the 'getLastId()' function returns zero. Note: The argumentos passed inside the  functions 'insertData()' and 'updateData()' are those just for test.

loggedin.php

```
else {

    $dataBase = new DB($db);
    $dataBase->insertData('name');
    //$dataBase->updateData('email', $dataBase->getLastId());

    if (isset($_POST['deleteAll'])) {
        $dataBase->deleteAll();
        header('Location: loggedin.php');
    }
    else if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $dataBase->deleteData($id);
        header('Location: loggedin.php');
    }

    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
....

</form>

        </h5>
        <?php
        echo 'Number of visits: ' .$dataBase->getLastId().'<br><br>';
        echo 'Relevant data: ' .$dataBase->fetch_row_count().'<br><br>';
        ?>
```

DB.php

```
class DB {
protected $_db;

    public function __construct(PDO $db) {
        $this->_db = $db;
    }
function insertData($firstName) {
        $insertUser = $this->_db->prepare("INSERT INTO `people` (first_name, created) VALUES (?, NOW())");
        $insertUser->bindValue(1, $firstName);
        $insertUser->execute();
    }
function updateData($mail, $last) {
    $updateData = $this->_db->prepare("UPDATE `people` SET `mail` = ? WHERE `id` = ?");
    $updateData->bindValue(1, $mail);
    $updateData->bindValue(2, $last);
    $updateData->execute();
}

    public function getLastId() {
        $last = $this->_db->lastInsertId();
        return $last;
    }
}
```

Comment: (you said they're only for test, but don't forget to replace the `$mail` variable with a proper `?` parameter in `$updateData`)

Comment: Yeh, i Have the ATTR::ERR... Besides i already test it with and 'updateData($mail, $last)' and the 'insertData()', they work fine. Thanks @Michael Berkowski, will do that

Comment: Wait, when you say that _if i call the function 'updateData()' the 'getLastId()' function returns zero_ are you referring to the `echo 'Number of visits: ' .$dataBase->getLastId().'<br><br>';` line?  That would be expected. `lastInsertID()` would not return a useful value after you execute another query (the update query)

Comment: That is what was unclear about your question, where you had commented out the `updateData()` call. You should not expect `getLastId()` to return a value after calling the update. You need to store its value in a variable after the `insertData()` if you need to use it again.

Comment: So i should return it (lastInsertId) in the insert function?

Comment: Just store it to a variable after `insertData()`.  $last_id = $database->getLastId();` and use the variable `$last_id` in the next call to `updateData()` as well as the echo: `echo 'Number of visits: ' . $last_id`

Comment: I would write this as an answer, but I cannot find where it is actually documented that `lastInsertId()` will return 0 following an update statement that follows an insert statement. This actually differs from the native MySQL behavior with the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function. Using the native function, it still returns the most recently inserted id even after an intermediary UPDATE statement. PDO does not appear to have documented its behavior...

Comment: Do you mind using my example to explain? i tried what i understood from that but didn't work. Thanks

Comment: `$dataBase->insertData('name'); $last_id = $dataBase->getLastId(); $dataBase->updateData('email', $last_id);` Then later, reuse it as `echo "Number of visits: $last_id";`

Comment: Thanks, i found that the problem can solve too by just calling the update function after the "echo 'Number of visits: ' .$dataBase->getLastId().'<br><br>';"

Comment: I will write what we found as an answer then, to detail the difference between MySQL's native functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDO's `lastInsertId()` method will apparently not return the same value from its most recent `INSERT` statement following any subsequent statement, based on my testing.  This behavior is not documented [in the `lastInsertId()` manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) although similar behavior is well understood for transactional queries.

For example, the following shows that even after an intermediary `SELECT` statement, the PDO object will no longer return the inserted id:

```
$p = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', '', '');
$p->query("INSERT INTO t (id) VALUES (null)");
echo $p-lastInsertId();
// prints 1

$p->query("SELECT * FROM t");
echo $p-lastInsertId();
// prints 0
```

This is different from MySQL's native behavior of the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function which *will* continue to return the most recently inserted id after subsequent `UPDATE` or `SELECT` statements.

Insert a row:

```
MariaDB [test]> INSERT INTO t3 VALUES (null);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
+------------------+
| LAST_INSERT_ID() |
+------------------+
|                6 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Execute an intermediary statement:

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT * FROM t3;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  3 |
|  6 |
+----+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The value is still available:

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
+------------------+
| LAST_INSERT_ID() |
+------------------+
|                6 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

To solve your issue, change the order of your operations to call your `updateData()` method after echoing out the previous id, or just store it into a variable for reuse.

```
$dataBase->insertData('name');
// Store the id into a variable
$last_id = $dataBase->getLastId();
// Use the variable in the update method call
$dataBase->updateData('email', $last_id);

// Later use the variable for output:
echo "Number of visits: $last_id";
```

Comment: Hello @Michael, sorry to bother. the problem now is that i'm calling the function in another file (index.php) and getLastId() works here , but i want the getLastId() to be displayed still on the loggedin.php, now it's returning 0 always

Comment: @Miguel If you have moved to a different script, you are now on a new database connection and even natively `PDO::lastInsertId()` would not return a value, nor `LAST_INSERT_ID()` directly to MySQL. If you need that value on a different script, you'll need to store it into `$_SESSION` or build a query to find it. Session is easier and faster.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.php  Call `session_start()` at the top of each page and assign the value `$_SESSION['last_id'] = $last_id;`